# How to call a set of code line only once in Scenario Outline in Karate API

Tags: api, karate

Scenario Outline: validate all fields
Given url 
Then def filePath= callonce read('../path') 
Then reqJson.<Request_Value> 
And request reqJson 
When method POST 
Then status 400
Examples:
| Request_Value                    | 
| filePath.requestValue1 = "value1"|
| filePath.requestValue2 = "value2"|

In the above Scenario outline Example, I need "**Then def filePath= callonce read('../path')**" will execute twice, but I need it to be executed only once.

Comment: It works fine for me. So maybe you found a bug in Karate. Please follow this process so that we can investigate: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue